# Using a file name string as a SystemVerilog interface parameter?

Tags: system-verilog

Is it possible to use a string as a SystemVerilog interface paramter.  I have 4 instances of the same interface, and I was wondering if I can `include different assertion files for each instance.

My interface looks like this:

```
interface dai_if #(P_WD_DATA = 24,
                   string P_FILE_NAME = "assertion_file_name")();


    //Internal Signal Defined Here


    `include "assertion_file_name"

endinterface : dai_if
```

In the top level, where I instantiate the four instances I have the following code:

```
module tb_top;

    parameter P_WD_DATA = 24;
    parameter string DAI_SER_IN_FILE  = "dai_ser_in_checkers.v";
    parameter string DAI_SER_OUT_FILE = "dai_ser_out_checkers.v";
    parameter string DAI_PAR_IN_FILE  = "dai_par_in_checkers.v";
    parameter string DAI_PAR_OUT_FILE = "dai_par_out_checkers.v";
```

Then I instanced each of the interfaces like this:

```
dai_if #(.P_WD_DATA(P_WD_DATA),
         .P_FILE_NAME(DAI_SER_IN_FILE))
         dai_ser_ivif();
```

Is this the correct method, or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use parameters to define include files as the `include macro is performed long before the parameters are evaluated (note that marcos such as `include and `define are run as part of preprocessing while parameters are defined and used during elaboration; a stage of compilation).

However, there are ways to get the desired behavior. Instead of using the parameter string to directly include a file, you can use it to conditionally instantiate the code from an include file like so:

```
module top;
  ...
  myInterface #(.assertType("TYPE1")) myInstance();
  ...

interface myInterface #(parameter assertType = "TYPE0") ();
  ...
  // NOTE: This is NOT inside any process block (like always, initial, etc)
  case (assertType)
    "TYPE0": begin
      `include "assert_type0.sv"
    end
    "TYPE1": begin
      `include "assert_type1.sv"
    end
    "TYPE2": begin
      `include "assert_type2.sv"
    end
  endcase
  ...
endinterface
```

In the above, during compilation, all the assertion code from all the files will be included, but the only ones to take affect will be those included in the file from branch of the case specified by the parameter, and the others will be left uninstantiated.